# How do you make the hat transparent but show the parts that are colored in?

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

I was trying to figure how to make this black part on the head transparent and the one that isn't black not transparent. This is 2.80[image]

Comment: Is the texture you're using transparent where the black is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Cycles and the black parts in a Image Texture, then you can use Mix Shader to use transparency.

[image: Material with transparent black parts based on non-transparent Image]

The other way (with Image Textures) is just using Transarency of the Image (png file with transparency e.g.).

[image: Transparency with using Alpha Channel of the Image]